# KeyError using `dask.merge()`

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dask

So I have two pandas dataframes created via

```
df1 = pd.read_cvs("first1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("second2.csv")
```

These both have the column `column1`. To double check,

```
print(df1.columns)
print(df2.columns)
```

both return a column `'column1'`.

So, I would like to merge these two dataframes with dask, using 60 threads locally (using an outer merge):

```
dd1 = dd.merge(df1, df2, on="column1", how="outer", suffixes=("","_repeat")).compute(num_workers=60)
```

That fails with a KeyError, `KeyError: 'column1'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "INSTALLATIONPATH/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4443)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4289)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13733)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13687)
KeyError: 'column1'
```

I would think this is a parallelizable task, i.e. `dd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')`

Is there a "dask-equivalent" operation for this? I also tried reindexing the pandas dataframes on `chr` (i.e. `df1 = df1.reset_index('chr')` ) and then tried joining on the index

```
 dd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

That didn't work either, same error.

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html

Comment: Are you calling dd.merge on `pandas.DataFrame` or on `Dask.dataframe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error, I would double check your initial dataframe to make sure you do have `column1` in both (no extra spaces or anything) as an actual column, because it should work fine (no error in the following code)

Additionally, there's a difference between calling merge on `pandas.DataFrame` or on `Dask.dataframe`.

Here's some example data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.arange(1000),
                           np.arange(1000)]), columns=['column1','column1_1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.arange(1000),
                           np.arange(1000, 2000)]), columns=['column1','column1_2'])
```

And their `dask` equivalent:

```
ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=100)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=100)
```

**Using `pandas.DataFrame`:**

```
In [1]: type(dd.merge(df1, df2, on="column1", how="outer"))

Out [1]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So this returns a pandas.DataFrame, so you cannot call `compute()` on it.

**Using `dask.dataframe`:**

```
In [2]: type(dd.merge(ddf1, ddf2, on="column1", how="outer"))
Out[2]: dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame
```

Here you can call `compute`:

```
In [3]: dd.merge(ddf1,ddf2, how='outer').compute(num_workers=60)

Out[3]:
   column1  column1_1  column1_2
0        0          0       1000
1      400        400       1400
2      100        100       1100
3      500        500       1500
4      300        300       1300
```

---

**Side Note**: depending on the size of your data and your hardware, you might want to check if doing a `pandas.join` wouldn't be faster:

```
df1.set_index('column1').join(df2.set_index('column1'), how='outer').reset_index()
```

Using a size of `(1 000 000, 2)` for each df it's faster than the dask solution on my hardware.

Comment: "Using a size of (1 000 000, 2) for each df it's faster than the dask solution on my hardware" Why would this join be quicker than a merge?

Comment: Because it's a different implementation than merge. pd.join works on index. It's consistently faster than pd.merge (a factor of 4 in this case). It's covered in a ton of questions on SO.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the help!